# Facebook appp only I get my email when login in the app

Tags: php, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm developing a Facebook app with facebook/php-sdk-v4, the scope is:

```
$permissions = ['email', 'public_profile'];
```

When I test the app all is ok, I can get my email, but whet other users login with their Facebook account I can't get their email address.

How I can get all emails of users that login in my app?

Comment: Thanks, inte Graph API Explorer givme this message "The email field was not returned. This may be because the email was missing, invalid or hasn't been confirmed.", So I bealive that error is in User account.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the php sdk you need to specify the fields you want using the field parameter in the request URL :

```
me?field=email
```

You also can use the Graph API Explorer to try your Graph request :

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/